# getting data from parse.com and showing it in a listview

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

i have a taxi booking application on Android and im trying to show previous bookings. Im trying to display these in a list view. I have a class called 'Booking' which holds the respective getters and setters. In my 'Booking' table on parse, I have 5 entries and 5 entries are shown on the listview, however the text isnt being shown?

Comment: Uber? J/k. Anyway, please post your code.